# MySQL create table with german date format for 2013

Tags: mysql, sql, date, create-table

I have this MySQL snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE MyDates
(
   mydate date
);

CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN

  WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
    INSERT INTO MyDates (mydate) VALUES (dateStart);
    SET dateStart = date_format(date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y');
  END WHILE;
END;//


CALL filldates('01.01.2013','31.12.2013');
```

Here I try to create a table for every day of this year but it does not work.

Without this specific date format it works well.

Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ae5c

Comment: Date does not have a format, just insert it as a Date/DateTime. Format for display purposes in your select query(ies).

Comment: Thank you. Well, I really need a DB with all days of a year to merge this with an other table.

Comment: Format for display purposes shouldn't even be done in select queries. It's done on application layer. The database should have nothing to do with it. Sebastian, please elaborate on your last comment.

Comment: This works pretty well. Thank you for the hint!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ae5c/15

Comment: It would be better if you just used the [ISO 8601 date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) on the database level and format into whatever format you desire for presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be looking for the `STR_TO_DATE()` function. 
Try something like

```
STR_TO_DATE(@dateInGermanFormat, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)